# Exit from bash script but keep the process running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm running a server and needs to execute following command with the parameters. The scripts works great at the moment but the problem is when I run the script I cannot return back to the console. It keeps running in the console. If I stop it forcefully then the the process also going to stop.

I want to keep running the process and return to the console.

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/stjc/app/artisan queue:listen --timeout=60 --tries=5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run that process in background:

```
#!/bin/sh
(php /home/stjc/app/artisan queue:listen --timeout=60 --tries=5) &
```

try adding an ampersand(`&`) at the end with brackets on either side of original command.

**Edit:**

`:` is a shell builtin which means NOP depending on your OS it might a problem try escaping the it in the php command and see if it works for you

```
#!/bin/sh
(php /home/stjc/app/artisan queue\:listen --timeout=60 --tries=5) &
```

also puting the full path to your `php` interpreter is strongly advised.

Comment: I do not see any problems with the command, it might be due to some typo you might have done or anything wrong within the `php` code itself.

Comment: Sounds like you used a Windows editor. Use `dos2unix` to fix the file, or see one of the huldreds of questions about this - it's a very common FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee Kindly explain more, I do not use windows.

Comment: Probably a wrong guess then; sorry. `: command not found` is very commonly seen when the script file has wrong line terminators.

Comment: @AchinthaSamindika `:` is a shell command. You're not pasting your real code; otherwise, the error you are describing would be impossible. Please post real code, real errors, and include the contents of your PATH in describing your configuration.

Comment: Rather than trying to escape things, simply quote it, e.g. `'queue:listen'`. That said I don't think that's the issue; a `:` isn't a special character other than as a command, so if it's part of an argument it'll work just fine. `echo foo:bar`, for instance, works.

Comment: @dimo414 it was just a wild guess, I know its not a problem on Ubuntu and Mac bash Terminals not sure about other envs.

Comment: It's not a problem in Bash.

Comment: Hi all, the solution worked. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`&` at the end of your command](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) to run a process in the background, or the [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command to disconnect a process from your terminal entirely so that it continues running even after you exit the shell.

The error `: command not found` is a separate problem. The text *before* the `:` is a command that the environment couldn't find. Since there's nothing before the `:` you're trying to start a command consisting of the empty string; here's an example:

```
$ foo
-bash: foo: command not found
$ ''
-bash: : command not found
```

Likely this is because you have a miss-set variable that you're using as a command, and therefore something is trying to to execute the empty-string command (which, of course, doesn't exist).

Comment: No, the variable will just be ignored then.  `$baa here` with `baa` unset produces `here: command not found`

Comment: @tripleee however `"$baa" here` will replicate the issue. The `:` command *does* exist, so that is clearly not causing OP's error message.

Comment: Agree that the colon command is a red herring.  In the meantime, I'm with CodeGnome in his comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Just append `&` after your command and the shell will run the job in the backend.It will returns something like:[1] 3633.`[1]` means shell job id, and `3633` means OS process id. If you want to stop the task, just simply type `kill 3633`.

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/stjc/app/artisan queue:listen --timeout=60 --tries=5 &
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option is there to send process in background as explained below:

Run script OR command you wish to run:
For example

```
girishp@~$ ping 10.137.108.192
PING 10.137.108.192 (10.137.108.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.18 ms
64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.367 ms
```

Press Ctrl+Z while command is running, It will stop running

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping 10.137.108.192
```

type `bg` in terminal to resume execution in background

```
 girishp@~$ bg
 [1]+ ping 10.137.108.192 &
 girishp@~$ 64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=5.46 ms
 64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=4.56 ms
```

You can again run it in foreground by typing `fg` in terminal:

```
girishp@~$fg
ping 10.137.108.192
64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=0.397 ms
64 bytes from 10.137.108.192: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=3.99 ms

(...)
```