# python script calling a shell script and i want to keep its process active even if the python script ends

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I want my python script to call a binary which will keep printing indefinitely. After calling the python script I want the binary to keep going.

life span is like this:

```
p--------->|
      |
      b------------>
```

"p" is the python script getting executed and soon after that the binary gets called from the python script and even after the python script is killed the binary keeps going.

I tried with subprocess.popen but after the python script is ended the process for the binary is also killed.

I also tried with os.popen but it's synchronous so it will keep waiting until the binary returns.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: This works.. "subprocess.Popen([name, input] )" : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `subprocess.Popen`.

Something like this:

main.py

```
import subprocess

print("Starting")
subprocess.Popen(["sh", "child.sh"])
print("Ending")
```

child.sh

```
while :
do
    echo "Something"
    sleep 1
done
```

The script will continue printing even after the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at these links to get more insight:**

- [Exit from bash script but keep the process running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114638/exit-from-bash-script-but-keep-the-process-running)
- https://superuser.com/questions/448445/run-bash-script-in-background-and-exit-terminal

In your case, let assume you have 2 files `run.py` and `script.sh` in the same dir.

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
    echo "script running"
    sleep 1
done
```

**run.py**

```
import subprocess
import sys


print("Starting script")
subprocess.run("bash ./script.sh", shell=True)

print("Finished. Script running in background")
```

To run the script in the background,add an ampersand at the end. Run `python run.py &` in your terminal, which returns a `process id` you can you to kill the process **e.g** `[1] 123520`. The process will start in the background, however it will still be logging the output in the terminal even if you press `ctrl + c`. To fix that just use add `nohup`, which will ignore the output. So run `nohup python run.py &`.